# JQuery loop duplicate result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a list of elements for an isotope page. The basic markup for an element is:

```
<div class="element conference-box"> <a href="#"><img src="#" class="conference-image" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="confback"></div>
      <h3 class="conference-title"></h3>
      <h4 class="conference-details"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

There around 30 or so elements on the page.

I've been trying to use jQuery to take the image with the class "conference-image" and apply it as a background image to the .confback div, while retaining the original image. I had some success using this code:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    var getImageSrc = $('.conference-image').attr('src');
    $('.confback').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
    return true;
});
```

However, my script takes the image from the very first element and applies that as the background image for every .confback div in every element on my page. Obviously, I would like each individual element to use the image that has been used in that particular element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `.each` function `$(this)` will be the elements with class `element`. You want to use the attributes and css of it's descendants, found using `find`:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    var getImageSrc = $(this).find('.conference-image').attr('src');
    $(this).find('.confback').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
});
```

Comment: Think you and James wrote the same solution word for word. Thank you both, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Within the `.each` callback, the `this` variable will be the `.element` that's currently being looped over.  You can use that to search within just that element for the `img` and `div` you want to work with by re-wrapping it with jQuery and using the [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    var getImageSrc = $(this).find('.conference-image').attr('src');
    $(this).find('.confback').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
});
```

Also note, the documentation for [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) says:

> Use `return false` to break out of each() loops early.

That doesn't mean you have to use `return true` to continue the loop, not returning anything is also valid - so I removed it from my example above.